# jQuery Autocomplete with 22000 items is very slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have installed jQuery Autocomplete (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Everything is OK, but I have 22,000 items & autocomplete is very slow.

Is here any solution?

Comment: It's always going to be slow dumping that much data in the DOM. Do the filtering server side instead.

Comment: so is here any solution? with connecting with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You should start autocomplete when user have entered at least **3 letters**. This will seriously decrease your item numbers.

```
if ($yourInput.val().length >= 3){
 ... launch autocomplete ...
}
```

EDIT :

As Wumpus said, you can use the minLength option to do it :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3
});
```

Comment: The autocomplete widget already has a `minLength` option for that purpose